# Custom 404 error page for non-existent actions in TYPO3

Tags: typoscript, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

For displaying a standard 404 error page when a non-existent Extbase action is called I use the "mvc.throwPageNotFoundExceptionIfActionCantBeResolved" parameter.

But how can I make TYPO3 invoke the error handler defined in [FE][pageNotFound_handling]?